# Setting up DAGS and Plugins with azure blob storage

Tags: config, airflow, azure-blob-storage

Is there a way to configure airflow to talk to microsoft azure blob storage for DAGS and PLUGINS folder

For the celery mode, would like to store these in BLOB storage instead of local shared folders.

Airflow version : 1.10.0

Configuration tyoe : celery executor

```
//Directory for log storage.
airflow_logs_dir: "/var/log/airflow"

//Location of Airflow plugins.
airflow_plugins_dir: "/usr/local/src/airflow/plugins"
```

Answer (score -1):

This apache airflow Python API Reference shows how to integration with Azure Blob Storage:[Microsoft Azure](https://airflow.apache.org/integration.html#azure-blob-storage).

And the module content you could refer to this page:[airflow.contrib.operators.file_to_wasb](https://airflow.apache.org/_api/airflow/contrib/operators/file_to_wasb/index.html#module-airflow.contrib.operators.file_to_wasb). This module is used to upload a file to Azure Blob Storage.

If you want sample code you could refer to this [file_to_wasb.py](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/tests/contrib/operators/test_file_to_wasb.py).

Comment: Hi George, this can be used for custom DAGS which developers use, but not part of the airflow configuration and installation.

Comment: I see an option to use blobfuse , have to try and use it in airflow config https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-how-to-mount-container-linux

Comment: Is there a proper example how to trigger dag on Azure Blob Upload ? I looked into the `airflow.contrib.sensors.wasb_sensor.WasbBlobSensor` but not sure how to use this to `trigger dag tasks` on a blob upload..